# NuSOAP using laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to use nusoap library in applications using laravel 4.
I have an update on the composer with NoiselabsNuSOAP :

[NuSOAP Library with composer](https://packagist.org/packages/noiselabs/nusoap-bundle)

And I have followed the user manual

My code :

```
public function CallSOAP()
    {
        $client = new \nusoap_client('http://mywebsite/services/VcareServices.php', true);
        $response = $client->call('validateLogin', array('EMAIL'=>'bertho_joris@yahoo.co.id', 'PASSWORD'=>'3b774f5aae6b97a060864f8310hg6785'));
        return $response;
    }
```

But I get an error message :

> UnexpectedValueException The Response content must be a string or
>   object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.

My question:

1. Is this library I can use for my laravel application?
2. How do I use to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's true maybe your SOAP response it's not the right one, but first of all try adding:

```
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8'; 
$client->decode_utf8 = false;
```

and check what is your service returning, maybe you have to specify the element of the response object like:

```
return $response['MyValue'];
```

or

```
return $response['key']['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the nusoap library is being loaded correctly, otherwise you would get an error about \nusoap_client not being a recognised function.

It is more likely that the endpoint you are working with (`http://mywebsite/services/VcareServices.php`) is not providing a valid SOAP response.

Check that your endpoint complies with the SOAP protocol, or test your client against an existing SOAP server that you know works. That should help you diagnose the problem.